# Checkmarx C# - Improper_Resource_Shutdown_or_Release

Tags: c#, checkmarx

I have a code block that looks like this:

```
        StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();
        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath.ToString());
        try
        {
            csvData.Append(Constants.CSVQuote);
            csvData.Append(Constants.Code);
            csvData.Append(Constants.CSVDelimiter);
            csvData.Append(Constants.Description);
            csvData.Append(Constants.CSVDelimiter);
            csvData.Append(Constants.Comments);
            csvData.Append(Constants.CSVQuote);

            fileWriter.WriteLine(csvData);
            csvData.Clear();
            for( int i=0; i<StatusEntities.Count(); i++)
            {
                csvData.Append(Constants.CSVQuote);
                csvData.Append(StatusEntities[i].Code != null ? Common.ToCSVString(StatusEntities[i].Code) : string.Empty);
                csvData.Append(Constants.CSVDelimiter);
                csvData.Append(StatusEntities[i].Description != null ? Common.ToCSVString(StatusEntities[i].Description) : string.Empty);
                csvData.Append(Constants.CSVDelimiter);
                csvData.Append(StatusEntities[i].Comments != null ? Common.ToCSVString(StatusEntities[i].Comments) : string.Empty);
                csvData.Append(Constants.CSVQuote);
                fileWriter.WriteLine(csvData);
                csvData.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fileWriter.Close();
            csvData = null;
        }
```

I keep getting back **Improper_Resource_Shutdown_or_Release** vulnerability.
I have tried using Automatic **Implicit release using try-with-resource** but that also didn't work.
Can you please provide some suggestions on how to fix this kind of vulnerability?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message/report you get from checkmarx and mark the lines mentioned in the error message/report in your source code (or provide the full file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkmarx is flagging your code because you aren't disposing of the new resource allocations properly for the StringBuilder and StreamWriter instances. You could move the resource allocation to the `try { }` block and then inside the `finally { }` block add the following code:

```
cvsData.Dispose(); 
fileWriter.Dispose();
```

The reason you need to move the resource allocations to the `try { }` block is because an exception can be thrown during allocation. Especially the following line:

```
StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath.ToString());
```

could throw an exception in the event the variable 'filepath' is invalid, for example.

Alternatively, you can wrap new resource allocations inside `using(...) { }` blocks such as the following:

```
using(var csvData = new StringBuilder())
{
    // work with csvData instance here
}
```

This ensures the resource is disposed of properly when it is out of scope (when you are done using it) without you needing to explicitly dispose of it.